# Why does ApiAuthorization not work in .NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-5, asp.net-core-5.0

I am using .NET Core API Authorization since version 3.1, which was working fine until I upgraded my project to .NET 5. After updating, I have been getting a `NullReferenceException`.

Here is the code from *Startup.cs*:

**ConfigureServices**

```
services.AddDbContext(options =>
    options.UseInMemoryDatabase("Databaase"));

services.AddDefaultIdentity()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores();

services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.SaveToken = true;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["Jwt:SecretKey"])),
            ValidAudience = configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero // Override the default clock skew of 5 mins
        };
    });
```

**Configure**

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

This is my **DbContext**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : ApiAuthorizationDbContext
```

**DbContext Constructor**

```
public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options, IOptions operationalStoreOptions, ICurrentUserService currentUserService, IDateTime dateTime) : base(options, operationalStoreOptions)
{
    _currentUserService = currentUserService;
    _dateTime = dateTime;
}
```

I am getting a `NullReferenceException` with following error details:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ConfigureApiResources.GetApiResources()+MoveNext()
    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ConfigureApiResources.Configure(ApiAuthorizationOptions options)
```

**Edit:**
Issue raised on GitHub https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/28456

Comment: Is the Exception message giving you the specific parameter that was null? How did you narrow it down to Authorization causing the issue?

Comment: Where in code is exception thrown?

Comment: When I run the application, the error shows in browser. Exception is not at any specific line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone is looking for the solution for this issue, as per the Github link provided in update, the issue was resolved by adding `Key` and `.AddIdentityServerJwt()`

**Key** must be be added to `appsettings.Development.json` as below:

```
"IdentityServer": {
    "Key": {
      "Type": "Development"
    }
  }
```

Also modifying the `Startup.cs` to include `.AddIdentityServerJwt()` as:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddIdentityServerJwt()
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.SaveToken = true;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["Jwt:SecretKey"])),
            ValidAudience = configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero // Override the default clock skew of 5 mins
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

your AddDefaultIdentity should be something like this

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
   .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

and remove

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();
```

and it should work

Comment: Thank you for your answer @ahmed-mohammed. I want to know if I need to inherit my `ApplicationDbContext` from any other class as it currently inherits from `ApiAuthorizationDbContext`?

Comment: I made the suggested changes and unfortunately it still does not work. Appreciate your time.

Comment: @DotnetDeveloper yes i changed ApiAuthorizationDbContext to IdentityDbContext but i don't remember why the browser console was very helpful to fix this one of the issue was the microsoft auth js library in the index.html page 

that line



<script src="_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication/AuthenticationService.js"></script>